# How can I scroll content horizontally with fullcalendar scheduler?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Using a heavily customized version of the scheduler, I'm getting reports that users are having trouble figuring out how to scroll horizontally. I imagine it's because the scrollbar is at the bottom of the schedule and on Mac OS, it's potentially hidden if the user has a trackpad.

My schedule functions similar to [this one](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.4.0/demos/json.html) minus the vertical scroll. If you're on an Apple laptop and only using trackpad it's likely you won't see a scrollbar at all. If the scroll bar is visible, it's buried under the page's fold.

Ideally, I'd have arrows near the times so users could click left or right and that view would scroll left or right. I've been unable to figure out a way to programmatically call $.animate({ scrollLeft: ... }) on any piece of the scheduler and scroll both the contents where events are *and* the header where times are.

It looks like I can get and set the position of at least the timeline with `$( '.fc-time-area .fc-content table' ).offset()` but it won't move the contents of the schedule itself.

Any idea how I can move the schedule content (events) and the timeline in sync with each other?

Bonus internet points if you can tell me how I could ensure that I'd only move the container to it's end. (i.e. If the schedule for that day ends at 10pm, don't allow me to change the offset to something beyond 10pm)

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: @RPichioli Did you see the part where I said "It looks like I can get and set the position of at least the timeline with $( '.fc-time-area .fc-content table' ).offset() but it won't move the contents of the schedule itself." or did you just tl;dr it when you didn't see a sizable code block. I'm happy to provide more information if you can think of something else that would clarify but because of the size of the calendar and code around it, it's a little tough to create much more of a reduced test case.

Comment: I have seen that. But just a jQuery selector working with "offset" don't give me the vision of what you have tried and scenario. Try to read something here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how I can move the schedule content (events) and the timeline in sync with each other?

To get to the beginning of the view:

```
$('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scroller').scrollLeft(0);
```

And for scrolling to the end of the view, you can do something as follows:

```
var scroller = $('.fc-body .fc-time-area .fc-scroller');
var scrollWidth = scroller[0].scrollWidth;
scroller.scrollLeft(scrollWidth);
```